# Fast differences of all row pairs with NumPy

Tags: python, optimization, numpy

I am using an algorithm that requires that each example has a matrix, say `Xi` which is `ai x b`, and that for each of the `O(n^2)` pairs of examples, I find the difference between each row `Xiu - Xjv`, then sum the outer products `sum_u sum_v np.outer(Xiu - Xjv, Xiu - Xjv)`.

Unfortunately this inner double sum is fairly slow, and is causing the running time to spiral out of control on large datasets.  Right now I'm just using for loops to do this.  Is there some pythonic way to speed up this inner operation?  I have been trying to think one up and having no luck.

To clarify, for each of the `n` examples, there's a matrix `Xi` with dimensions `ai x b` where `ai` is different for each example.  For each pair `(Xi, Xj)` I want to go through all the `O(ai * bi)` pairs of rows between the two matrices and find `Xiu - Xjv`, take the outer product of that with itself `np.outer(Xiu - Xjv, Xiu - Xjv)`, and finally sum all those outer products.

For instance:  Suppose D is `[[1,2],[3,4]]` and we're just working with that for both matrices.

Then i.e. one step might be `np.outer(D[0] - D[1], D[0] - D[1])` which would be the matrix `[4,4],[4,4]`.

Simply enough, (0,0) and (1,1) are just 0 matrices, and (0,1) and (1,0) are both 4 matrices, so the final sum of all four outer products of pairs would be `[[8,8],[8,8]]`.

Comment: I would suggest adding a concrete example - it will help more people  understand the problem.

Comment: Is what you really want the squared Euclidean distance between all pairs of vectors?  because there are shortcuts to that.

Comment: No, the opposite of the squared Euclidean distance -- outer product.  Example coming.

Comment: I see. I can't help thinking there must be a simplification of this at the algebraic rather than the implementation level.

Comment: Note that `a^T (b c^T) d = (a^T b) (c^T d)` and `sum_i v_i = 1^T v`.  You should be able to take it from there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK this one was fun.  I still can't help thinking it can all be done with a single ingenious call to `numpy.tensordot` but at any rate this seems to have eliminated all Python-level loops:

```
import numpy

def slow( a, b=None ):

    if b is None: b = a
    a = numpy.asmatrix( a )
    b = numpy.asmatrix( b )

    out = 0.0
    for ai in a:
        for bj in b:
            dij = bj - ai
            out += numpy.outer( dij, dij )
    return out

def opsum( a, b=None ):

    if b is None: b = a
    a = numpy.asmatrix( a )
    b = numpy.asmatrix( b )

    RA, CA = a.shape
    RB, CB = b.shape    
    if CA != CB: raise ValueError( "input matrices should have the same number of columns" )

    out = -numpy.outer( a.sum( axis=0 ), b.sum( axis=0 ) );
    out += out.T
    out += RB * ( a.T * a )
    out += RA * ( b.T * b )
    return out

def test( a, b=None ):
    print( "ground truth:" )
    print( slow( a, b ) )
    print( "optimized:" )
    print( opsum( a, b ) )  
    print( "max abs discrepancy:" )
    print( numpy.abs( opsum( a, b ) - slow( a, b ) ).max() )
    print( "" )

# OP example
test( [[1,2], [3,4]] )

# non-symmetric example
a = [ [ 1, 2, 3 ], [-4, 5, 6 ], [7, -8, 9 ], [ 10, 11, -12 ] ]
a = numpy.matrix( a, dtype=float )
b = a[ ::2, ::-1 ] + 15
test( a, b )

# non-integer example
test( numpy.random.randn( *a.shape ), numpy.random.randn( *b.shape ) )
```

With that (rather arbitrary) example input, timing of `opsum` (measured using `timeit opsum(a,b)` in IPython) looks only about a factor of 3–5 better than `slow`. But of course it scales *much* better: scale up the numbers of data-points by a factor of 100,  and the number of features by a factor of 10,  and then we're already looking at about a factor-10,000 increase in speed.

Comment: By the way, how did you come up with this?  Were there some algebraic laws that you used?

Comment: Would be nice if I could claim to know the algebra outright. In fact I broke it down into its pieces before reassembling from first principles. I.e. write the whole problem as a quadruple-nested
loop with a single *scalar* term at its heart: `out[rOut,cOut] += (a[rA,rOut] - b[rB,rOut]) * (a[rA,cOut] - b[rB,cOut])`
Then multiply that out, treating each of the resulting four terms separately. Figure out (by drawing it on paper) what each one means as a matrix multiplication.  Re-write them as `numpy` products.
Then keep nipping and tucking at the code to optimze for performance.

Comment: @AndrewLatham I've changed the formulation to look algebraically neater/more symmetrical. Maybe that'll help with the intuition as to what's going on.  To my surprise, there's even a small performance increase.

Comment: Hey jez, later on I've run into a similar algorithm (these come from manual modifications of Fisher Discriminant Analysis) that requires a very slightly different calculation, would you mind taking a look?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31145918/fast-weighted-scatter-matrix-calculation?lq=1